# There is no Armenian in Logitech K480 physical keyboard language list

Tags: samsung, languages, external-keyboard

I have a Samsung Tab A8 (Android 12). Recently I bought a Bluetooth keyboard Logitech K480 to go with it. For English, the keyboard works as expected, however I noticed that there is no Armenian language when I am typing with Logitech K480 there are no layouts.

Is there a way to add/install Armenian so I could use it with the physical keyboard (without 3rd party apps)? As I see it, it is a software thing since the keyboard sends the same signals only the mapping is different.

If not, is there a way to do such a thing with 3rd party apps?

Answer (score 0):

On Android additional keyboard layouts are provided via [Key Character Map](https://source.android.com/docs/core/interaction/input/key-character-map-files) files. 3rd party apps can have such files built-in.
You should take a loot at [More Physical Keyboard Layouts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=varzan.extraKeyboardLayouts) app that provide some extra layouts. It's free and [open source](https://github.com/calin-darie/extra-keyboard-layouts).